# Restore Original Template of the Control

Tags: wpf

about 90% of the application uses a template I have written for a "Button",  which I am overriding as:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"> .........</Style>
```

However, at one particular place I would like to use the default "Button" template, (this getting overridden as I am not specifying a key on the style) any thoughts on how I can achieve->  "apply the above template everywhere expect here"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button Style="{x:Null}"/>
```